# Bash: How to redirect the output of set of commands piped together to a file?

Tags: bash

```
perf record | perf inject -b | perf report > tempfile 2>&1
```

I am running the above set of commands and trying to capture the ouput to temfile, but sometimes the outputs doesn't get fully appended in the tempfile (output of each command). To be more precise I am running this command from a script and I tried putting them in small brackets like

```
(perf record | perf inject -b | perf report) > tempfile 2>&1
```

but this also didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pipe redirects output of one program to another. To log the output to a file **and** redirect to another program use `tee` command:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_(command)